# PHP CodeIgniter API not receiving JSON data

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, codeigniter

I am creating a REST API with PHP CodeIgniter paired with an MYSQL Database and an AngularJS Frontend. This is how my Database Table looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/piMZS.png

**What Works**

- I tested this API with a POST request from POSTMan like and it works perfectly.

```
account_name : "Test User 2"
display_name : "Test 2"
phone_no : 2832532
email : james@gmail.com
```

- This is the PHP response

```
Array
(
    [account_name] => Test User 2
    [display_name] => Test 2
    [phone_no] => 2832532
    [email] => james@gmail.com
)
```

**What Doesn't work**

- I am sending a request from Angular using HTTP Client. The Code:

```
  onSubmit(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append("Content Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    let postData = {
      account_name : "Test User 2",
      display_name : "Test 2",
      phone_no : "2832532",
      email : "james@gmail.com"
    }

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user-info/create-user", JSON.stringify(postData), {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
     }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(postData))
    })
  }
}
```

- The issue is after JSON.stringify(postData) the postData becomes

```
{"account_name":"Test User 2",
"display_name":"Test 2",
"phone_no":"2832532",
"email":"james@gmail.com"}
```

- And I get an Internal Server Error 500

```
code: 500
message: "Column 'account_name' cannot be null"
title: "mysqli_sql_exception"
```

- And the PHP Response is

```
Array
(
    [account_name] => 
    [display_name] => 
    [phone_no] => 
    [email] => 
)
```

- The data is not receiving PHP whenever **account_name becomes "account_name"**

Any help with this will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From angular you POST the data as JSON. My guess is that with POSTMAN you send the data as form-data.

You could try the following:

```
onSubmit(){
  var formData: any = new FormData();
  formData.append("account_name", "Test User 2");
  formData.append("display_name", "Test 2");
  formData.append("phone_no", "2832532");
  formData.append("email", "james@gmail.com");

  this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/user-info/create-user", formData)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
   }, error => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(formData)
  })
}
```

Or change your PHP code to accept JSON.